# Current Loation is not picking in android

Tags: android, google-maps, itemizedoverlay

I am now moving with a project related to Google Map service. I would like to point out my current location in my map. For that, I have got an idea of using itemizedoverlay. I retrieve the current location by the help of Geopoint. But when I'm used the itemizedoverlay in my code, the location cannot be picked up and I am using this in my OnCreate method. If I am moving this to OnLocationChanged method, then GeoPoint(point) will not be picked up by the itemizedoverlay and will end with an error and in the present condition, the app gets crushed down.

```
        MapView mapView;
    Location location;
    LocationManager locationmanager;
    LocationListener locationlistener; 

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

      mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
      mapView.setTraffic(true);
      mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        //locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
   // locationlistener = new GPSLocationListener();
      //  locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER 0,0,locationlistener);                                                                                         

      GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
                " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
      Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);


          HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
          OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,"","" );
          itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
          mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

}

/*      private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener 
      {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          if (location != null) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
                " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,"","" );
              itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
              mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

}
        } */


    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"GPS Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"GPS Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Can you please suggest me a solution for this?? Thanks In Advance and sorry if I made any mistakes here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay which will automatically get show your location on your map view. It will even update your location when travelling.

Note: you show call enableMyLocation and disableMyLocation on onResume and onPause respectively for better performance.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (locationOverlay != null)
            locationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (locationOverlay != null)
            locationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
        super.onPause();
    }
```

**EDITED**

```
MyLocationOverlay locationOverlay;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
      mapView.setTraffic(true);
      mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
locationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
 mapOverlays.add(locationOverlay);
}
```

also add the onResume() and onPause() methods.

Comment: Eventhough I am not getting the current location in map, will it work brother?

Comment: The GPS location is not always available specially in Indoor. So if you have setup location listener for GPS Provider and you are indoor then you may not receive the gps signal. The MyLocationOverlay find which provider to use and setup the location listener and get you the location

Comment: If you see the documentation of enableMyLocation it says "Attempts to enable MyLocation, registering for updates from LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER and LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER." So it register both provider and you no need to worry about setup of listeners and updating the overlay again for an update.

Comment: Can you please post the code for this : com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay. Yesterday onwards I am trying for this, but still having no idea. I found this method on somewhere else. But don't know how to use it in my code. I tried my maximum. Sorry to say that I am not much experienced in the field.

Comment: Hi Vivek, Thanks for your kind and early reply; also I have a doubt, that without retrieving a location (Geopoint), how we can point out it in the map?

Comment: MyLocationOverlay is taking care of getting your location from the GPS provider and Network Provider. So we dont have to do anything except add the overlay to mapview.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this -

```
/**
* Setting Google Map to provided location 
*/
 private void setMaptoLocation(Location location) {
  mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  mapView.setSatellite(true);
  int LAT = (int)(location.getLatitude() * 1E6) ;
  int LNG = (int)(location.getLongitude() * 1E6) ;
  GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(LAT, LNG);
  mapController = mapView.getController();
  List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
  Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
  HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
  OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,"","" );
  itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
  mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
  mapController.setZoom(ZOOM_LEVEL - ZOOM_LEVEL / 2); // Set zoom level per requierment
  mapController.animateTo(point);

 }
```

Comment: This also is not working for me brother. Showing some error with drawable.

Comment: Oh...I though you would add drawable..anyways...I have edited my post...plz..use now...still getting error..plz post logcat

Comment: Here also, the location showing is somewhere else. Seems to be nearer to Gulf of Guinea in south Africa. I think it may be related with the geopoint issue. But it works somewhat. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Good to know that It worked . About the location not sure how are you passing the location to this functions. It should be- setMaptoLocation((int)(location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

Comment: whatever lat/longs ..you are getting , you can cross check in Google Map on web too.

Comment: while giving : setMaptoLocation((int)(location.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6)); The app automatically crushes down saying, the mapactivity has stopped unexpectedly. I was just given setMaptoLocation(int Lat, int Lon);

Comment: I know I am at the door and just a step away from success. But, for that I need your help. If you don't mind., can you please edit your code with this suggestion?

Comment: That's what I was saying, while giving so,the app automatically crushes saying the error, the map activity has stopped unexpectedly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23145/discussion-between-gaurav-jain-and-tony)

Comment: Updated in Chat...plz check !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to go with the `Google Maps Android API v2`

For the more information check the [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start).

please check the link of the sample code from the above link. 
[sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. But, the link do not explain what I really want. It only deals with getting a map. I would like to point the current location in my map with an icon.

Comment: there is a link for the sample code in that link.please check my updated code.

Comment: @Rahul why? What's the necessity?

Comment: @Coder not necessary. but using API v2, we can got it easy way.

Comment: @RahulPatel i think your answer is not related and should be down voted

Answer (score 0):

**location** is no where initialize by you in **onCreate()** so i guess its null. And one more thing if you got Lat and Long, itemized will surely show location on Map.
Check permission required **Access_Course_location** and **Access_fine_location** in Manifest.

Comment: I have already defined that in the manifest brother. Also it has been provided with:                                             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Is your Toast show lat and long? you no where register Location Manager then how can you read location